# SSRS and SharePoint List - rsSPDataProviderError when changing fields

Tags: list, reporting-services

I have a report saved to a SharePoint library.  With that report, I have a shared dataset and datasource.  The report, dataset, and datasource are linked together.

I recently made a change to a SharePoint list that the dataset pulls data from.  This change included the removal and addition of a field.

When I attempt to view the report, I get this error:
[image]

This error only occurs in one of three different environments.  I have granted permissions to the list so that anyone can read the data.

I have tried to modify the report using Report Builder 3.0; nothing I do seems to work.  The closest I got was a report with no data presented.  There has to be something wrong with the shared dataset, but I don't see what I could have changed between this environment and the other two.

Has anyone come across this issue?  I believe it follows something similar with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890209/report-builder-3-0-rsspdataprovidererror

**UPDATE**

I found out why my report came out empty was because the default view was filtered and I lacked conditions in my dataset's query. So now everything shows correctly on the Report Builder. But even after saving it and trying to access it from a report webpart, I still get that same error.

Answer (score 0):

- Modify the report using Report Builder 3.0.
- Go to the dataset.
- Refresh your fields.

[image]

- Make sure that the old fields are not included in your query.
- Press Ok , click Run to make sure it's render properly.
- Save and check your report in SharePoint.

**Note:** If you are using a CAML query try to run it with UTU tool then make sure that it does not include your removed fields.then replace it with the old query in your dataset.

Comment: That's what I do.  But the field that the error says it can't find is the new field.  And I checked the list for the internal name and refreshed the fields repeatedly.

Comment: Friday night I just found out why my report came out empty was because the default view was filtered and I lacked conditions in my dataset's query.  So now everything shows correctly on the Report Builder.  But even after saving it and trying to access it from a report webpart, I still get that error.